# MongoDB: $and with an ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
$and: [{
            _id: {
                $ne: _id
            }
        }, {
            _id: {
                $nin: student.request_send
            }
        }],
```

Not working as aspected none query ran.

**I am trying to implement a friend request feature so I write this query to find all the people except himself and already requested people.

_id is the senders _id and student is data of the sender
**

Comment: Is the _id and id's within student.request_send in ObjectId or string format? It should be in the former.

Comment: `{"_id":{"$oid":"60eaeb54aeaa9c4aa88c30e2"},"topics":[],"connection":null,"request_send":[{"$oid":"60e8040d3ab4861b5020178c"}],"request_receive":[],"profile_picture":null,"created_at":{"$date":"2021-07-11T12:57:10.082Z"},"active":true,"verified":false,"email":"ssa@999.com","username":"sapta","password":"$2a$10$xELefLiKV/V5C2nSRvPCKeCk/KrSXcjwfls16z3psn3GmvyoZB7Qu","goal":1,"exp":10,"__v":0}`

Comment: Like i said the query is correct, just check the type of value in _id and request_send array. It cannot be in string format, but ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine. Are you sure you are storing correct data in **student**? Can you please add example?

Comment: `{"_id":{"$oid":"60eaeb54aeaa9c4aa88c30e2"},"topics":[],"connection":null,"request_send":[{"$oid":"60e8040d3ab4861b5020178c"}],"request_receive":[],"profile_picture":null,"created_at":{"$date":"2021-07-11T12:57:10.082Z"},"active":true,"verified":false,"email":"ssa@999.com","username":"sapta","password":"$2a$10$xELefLiKV/V5C2nSRvPCKeCk/KrSXcjwfls16z3psn3GmvyoZB7Qu","goal":1,"exp":10,"__v":0}`